# How to make the font a little thicker/bolder?

Tags: fonts, pdf

I typeset a book with some ttf/otf fonts, when printed it seems ok, but it is a little fuzzy when view on screen or on mobile devices. Another problem is one font does not match very well with another one but will be much better if it is a little thicker/bolder.

So my question is how to make one font face looks a little thicker? With TeXnical or non-TeXnical methods both fine.

Comment: There are some "poor-mans bold" techniques which print a text multiple times with slightly different placing to make it look bolder. However, this is only for small amounts of text. I don't think this will work for the whole document. I think you will really just have to find another font or variant of your current font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is generally to use the right font variant. If you're using a professional font, you might want to buy that variant (usually called "bold" or "black").

If that is not an option, you could search for a similar font that looks more bold.

About matching fonts, quite a few fonts are designed by pairs: one serif and one sans-serif matching. For example, Adobe Minon Pro (serif) is made to be used together with Myriad Pro (sans-serif), or Linux Libertine (serif) is made to be used with Linux Biolinum (sans-serif).